# PHP Mysql COUNT results in a double loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, count, while-loop

I would like to know how can I count the results in case I have two loop ! :

```
$select = "SELECT X FROM Y"

$result = mysql_query($select,$link);

$total = mysql_num_rows($result);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $Name = $row['X'];
    $select2 = "SELECT id FROM `".$Name."` ";
    $result2 = mysql_query($select2,$link) or die ('Erreur : '.mysql_error() );
    $total2 = mysql_num_rows($result2);
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) { echo $row2['id']} }
```

I would like to count how many id I have at the end . Thanks for your help

Comment: Which result? Any idea?

Comment: count many id I got at the end

Comment: see my answer @Moon's Light

Comment: use SELECT COUNT(X) AS countX FROM Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just give this

```
$select = "SELECT X FROM Y"

$result = mysql_query($select,$link);

$total = mysql_num_rows($result);

$finalTotal=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$Name = $row['X'];
$select2 = "SELECT id FROM `".$Name."` ";
$result2 = mysql_query($select2,$link) or die ('Erreur : '.mysql_error() );
$total2 = mysql_num_rows($result2);
 $finalTotal = $finalTotal + $total2;
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) { echo $row2['id'];} }

echo "total id is ".$finalTotal;
```

$finalTotal will show you total number of id's

Comment: That means I can obtain how many id I have without doing the second loop ?

Comment: You have to see my statement in second while loop i am adding the id's here $finalTotal = $finalTotal + $total2;

Comment: this is generally not a good way count required <b> field </b> from Database

Comment: But here the query is fetching 'id' and obviously $result2 must have id and hence $count2 will inderctly give what we what, logically it works.

Comment: it works but there's still a problem because I must do a limit 0,60 to limite the results otherwise I will have 100.000 results , this method just show exactly 60 results , how can I count all of them then ?

Comment: yeah I put them only in my code now at :   `$select2 = "SELECT id FROM \`".$Name."\` LIMIT 0,60";` otherwise I get the error : Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted

Comment: @chandresh_cool do you know how to automatically delete tables that are 7 days old and everyday. I have no less than 80 tables.

Comment: It is possible bt y shud hv a column tht contains date column